# How do i create a Randomized, endless animation on an imageview

Tags: java, android, objectanimator

I would like to create a Randomized, endless animation on an imageview.

I have already implemented the animation, and the imageview floats from the bottom of the screen to the top. But when it arrives there it starts over again, i would like it to be randomized and endless.

```
 public void animateBubbles() {

    for (final ImageView img : IMGS) {


        animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img, "translationY", 0f, -deviceHeight);
        animation.setDuration(6000);
        animation.start();
        animation.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);

        animation.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
                img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            }
        });



    }
}
```

Comment: I found it not clear, do you want it to "bounce" on the top and go back to bottom, or just the animation to "restart" from the bottom and go again to top (like an infinite amount of bubble going up) ?

Comment: Like an infinite amount of bubbles going up

Comment: do you want this https://www.lottiefiles.com/363-beer-bubbles ???

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Start the *second* animation from top to bottom in the `onAnimationEnd()` of the *first* animation.
For repeating both animations one after another, remove `setRepeatCount()` property from these animations and call the **whole animation logic** again from the `onAnimationEnd()` method of the *second* animation

Comment: I have created a second animation and tried to call the method, but nothing is being displayed.     
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    secondAnimation();


                }

Comment: How do you initialize second object animator?

Comment: The same as the first one I just changed the values, I think it doesn't work because of this line. 
        animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(img, "translationY", 0f, -deviceHeight);
        I set the animation to end at -deviceHeight but it doesn't stop there. It continues so the onAnimatomEnd method is never called. Do you know how I can stop the animation when it reaches the devices actionbar.